# Lsass.exe high CPU usage on Windows Server 2016

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2016, lsass

My website runs on Windows Server 2016. It looks as follows:

- IIS with 3 applications running with SSL:

  - MVC website (.Net Framework 4.7).
  - Two .Net Core 3.1 Api's.
- MS SQL Express 2019.

If the traffic increases, the CPU for lsass.exe (yellow) increases dramatically:

[image]

In the end it takes so much CPU that my own applications get slow. I searched on the internet, most problem solving is linked to MS Active Directory. However, this is not installed on the server.

My question: Does anyone know how to identify which process is causing this behaviour? Is it a virus, MS SQL, SSL??

Comment: lsass is related to authentication, is your .Net applications performing authentication, or group membership verifications for example ?

Comment: one of the api's is an authentication api that produces JWT access tokens.

Comment: The most accurate way to learn why is to capture hang dumps of that process and analyze. If analyzing native dumps is not what you are familiar with, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com BTW, it is recommended to host web server and database on separate machines.

Comment: @kloarubeek any solution for the CPU spike with LSASS.exe?

Comment: @saravana no, didn't find anything :-(